# Hagbah of the Yemenites (Temanim)

Tags: torah-service, yemenite-temani, hagbah-gelilah

I was learning in a sefer which discusses a case where they couldn't do hagbah, and the Mechaber suggested to do the hagbah like the Teimanim which is to leave it on table in some way, but I didn't fully grasp how it's done. Is there a picture of their technique or a description how it's done?

Comment: the teimonim leave the torah case on the table and lift the parchment up

Comment: How can that be done with an ashkinazi Torah,that's exactly how he explained ot but I am having trouble conceptualizing it

Comment: an ashkanazi torah is the same laying down as a teimoni/safaradi torah in a case. it is roled onto the sticks in the end. therefore when it is laying down you would just lift the parchment up in the middle

Comment: How do they touch the parchment without their hands?Also how high is it lifted

Comment: teimonim use the hanker chiefs which are used to cover the torah. if it is ashkanazim they can use a taleeth

Comment: I feel like I am over thinking it,the procedure is basically the Torah is placed on the bimah then they lift the parchment slightly and then roll it up ,or close it,just the raising up trying to picture,a photograph or vid would be great

Comment: the torah is place on the bimoh laying down and the parchment is lifted up in the middle with the cloth. then it is put back in place and rolled back into the case or rolled up the ashkanazi way if it is an ashkanazi torah

Comment: Hey @sam -- does [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10195/5323) help you?

Comment: @Shokhet thats not how teimonim do it

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob OK....I don't know how teimonim do it, but thought that might be relevant. Guess not.

Comment: Sefardi hagbah I have seen,teimani I have never seen and don't even know where to see,anyone I know that is teimani davens in a sefardic minyan not teimani

Comment: @sam http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Beth_Yaacov_Torah.JPG see how the torah is laying spread out. now imagine you standing in front of it. life the parchment in the middle thats it. then roll it back out flat

Comment: Got it that's what I thought ,the main question is how high is the lift two inches? Or a foot so the congregation can see the letters.Meaning does it look like a hill ,or just a little lift.

Comment: @sam it looks like a hill

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, sounds like you have an answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @msh210 can you do it for me? :)

Comment: http://www.ybz.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/Article_65.5%281%29.pdf whoever wants to read it and summarize it can go right ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a picture of their technique or a description how it's done?

Screen cap from [the link](http://www.ybz.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/Article_65.5%281%29.pdf) that [MoriDoweedhYaa3qob](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2352/moridoweedhyaa3qob) posted:

[image: Hagba, Teiman style]

Using some cloth (Talith or similar) the parchment is lifted to about head-height. To do this, one would have to *unroll* the Sefer Torah while lifting it.

Probably best to grab it at the seam (which you can find every 3 to 4 columns).

After the *Hagba* is over, one would have to roll back the slack while slowly lowering it.

Comment: Thank excellent answer ,and thanks to Moridorweedhyaa3qob