# Are any communities using Sifrei Torah without "rollers"?

Tags: sefer-torah

I think there was some mention in Mas. Megillah that discussed the method of doing hagbah and the usage of a *mitpachat* ("kerchief / cloth") for handling and covering the Torah. From this idea, it seems that Sifrei Torah, originally, did not use *atzei chayim* (the wooden rollers to which the parchment is attached to.)

These days, I've seen Sifrei Torah attached to rollers or encased for Sephardim. Are there any communities / nuscha'ot that still use Sifrei Torah without the rollers?

Comment: Why not ask first about the alleged Talmud in Megillah before asking if your conclusion from it is "still" practiced??

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47871/11532