# What are the Sephardic responses during weekday shacharit?

Tags: synagogue, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, how-to, shacharis-morning-prayer

During the repetition of the Amidah, during Ata Kodesh, Sephardim say "emet". And during Yivarecha, they say "Yehi Ratzon". However, these may be shared by *nusach* Ashkenaz, so is there is a list of uniquely Sephardic responses at *shacharit* on a weekday?

The usual responses are just Amen at the end of each blessing. However, during certain parts of the prayers other responses are said such as "yasher koach", "Yehi Ratzon" and "emet." There's not very much, but I just don't know them.

Comment: I suppose you've already listed the ones I can recall, maybe I could add responses to Kaddish and the parts said together in _Uva leTzion._ And they begin with ה' מלך, some add אמת after each _aliyah._ Regarding narrowing your question, we'd be all better off if you could choose a more exact part of the the roughly 1 hour long prayer.

Comment: Maybe one of you could Community Wiki an answer that includes all of the above. The [closest relative of this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10195/3) is only answered by individuals, but I think a wikied list would fit well here.

Answer (score 3):

Different customs exist among Sephardic communities. Here is a (doubtless partial) list of such responses I've heard in Sephardic communities and not (or very rarely) in Ashkenazic ones:

### in the leader's repetition of the *amida*

- after "ואלקי יעקב" in the first benediction is "עליהם השלום"
- after "מוריד הטל" or "ומוריד הגשם" in the second benediction is "לברכה"
- after "ומצמיח ישועה" in the second benediction is "בקרוב"
- after "אתה קדוש" and after "ושמך קדוש", both in the third benediction, is "אמת"
- after "בשובך לציון ברחמים" in the third-to-last benediction is "כמאז"
- after "וכל החיים יודוך סלה" in the second-to-last benediction is (I think) "ברוך חַי העולמים"

Comment: This answer is a community wiki, which means it's easier for others to edit (and, incidentally, I get no reputation points from upvotes to it). Please contribute to it!

Comment: Do we talk about Nusach Sefard, Sefardi or Mizrachim?

Comment: @kazi dunno about _we_, but _I_ meant Sephardic in a broad sense (including Mizrachim) but not the Ashkenazic _nusach "S'farad"_.

Comment: Edited to add a few: added "bekarov" in the second blessing and corrected the second-to-last blessing to be "barukh hai ha'olamim". Source: Darké Abotenou.