# Repeated Hagbah by the same individual

Tags: synagogue, torah-service, hagbah-gelilah

From [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45620/how-to-display-the-torah-when-doing-hagbah), it's clear that there is a halachic requirement to do a "good" hagbah.  [This one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52911/lechatchila-to-begin-with-can-the-gabbai-call-someone-to-do-hagbah-when-he-kno) emphasizes that, by saying that a gabbai who *knows* the individual can't do a good job shouldn't call them.

Given that, if there is only one person in the congregation who *is* capable of doing a good hagbah, should they be called twice on a day where multiple Torahs are used?  All three times on Simchat Torah?  Can they be called for an aliyah in addition to hagbah (even when there's only one Torah)?

Comment: +1 for the question. CYLOR. But, I think it would be a good idea to call that one person up as many times as needed before announcing publicly the date and time of the demonstration and practice in hagbah.

Comment: +1 It could be a shul with nine 80-year-olds and one 40 year old.